# How to fix Cygwin installation, when unable to update setup?

Tags: cygwin, updates

I have Cygwin installed on my Windows 10 system. Every now and then I run Cygwin Setup to add packages as needed (mostly scripting interpreters). For some time now I face a problem when trying to install new packages. Specifically, I run `setup-x86_64.exe`, go through the first several dialogs and select the Download Site, usually `mirrors.kernel.org` (both `http:` and `https:` versions, and I also tried other sites). Then, the connection process starts and I get the following pop-ups:

[image]

[image]

This repeats about four times and ends with:

[image]

My machine has no real problem connecting to the site, as I can ping it successfully. Also, as said, this happens with other sites as well.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this, preferably w/o a complete uninstall-install cycle of Cygwin?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the latest `setup-x86_64.exe`

Comment: I did not, but will give it a try.

Comment: @DavidPostill - that's great, thanks. Seems like it has passes the problematic point, and I was able to download Perl. Why don't you make this an actual answer?

Comment: Answer posted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why is this happening and how can I fix this, preferably w/o a complete uninstall-install cycle of Cygwin?

The symptoms you describe sound like it might be an issue with an out of date version of `setup-x86_64.exe`.

You can download the latest version here [setup-x86_64.exe](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe).

[ysap](https://superuser.com/users/45564/ysap) who posted the question has confirmed that running the latest `setup-x86_64.exe` has resolved his issue in a [comment on the question](https://superuser.com/questions/1738784/how-to-fix-cygwin-installation-when-unable-to-update-setup?noredirect=1#comment2693555_1738784)

Comment: Thanks. I am a little confused, though, as the existing setup program was used for the current installation! Why would it become out-of-sync now?

Comment: There may have been a change to the way the mirrors respond that broke the old setup.

Comment: For what its worth I cannot reproduce your issue with a 2 year old version of setup.